# tag friend on a Post

Tags: tags, tagging, facebook-wall

Hello I'm trying to taga  friend in a wall post with officials graph api.
As reported on documentation

> #### **message_tags**
>
> *Objects tagged in the message (Users, Pages, etc)* (Requires access_token)
>
> object containing fields whose names are the indexes to where objects are mentioned in the message field; each field in turn is an
> array containing an object with id, name, offset, and length fields,
> where length is the length, within the message field, of the object
> mentioned

```
var array = {'data':{'id':XXXXXXXXXX, 'name':'Friend name','offset':0,'length':11}};
        
Facebook.code.WallPost({
    "access_token" : Titanium.App.Properties.getString('access_token'),
    "message" : $("#post_message").val(),
    "message_tags" : array
});
```

Facebook.code.WallPost is a custom javascript function to post.

```
WallPost : function(data) {
    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      dataType : "json",
      url : "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed",
      data : data,
      success : function(data) {
        alert("posted");
      },
      error : function(data) {
        alert("not posted");
      }
  });
}
```

With my code post has been published but without tag!
Someone can help me?
Thank you, Stefano

Answer (score 0):

The story_tags field contains information about the people and pages tagged in the story, and is in exactly the same format as the existing **message_tags** field on the Post object. For example:

```
{
 . . .
      "story": "Dhiren Patel likes Marmot.",
      "story_tags": {
        "19": [
          {
            "id": 101961456910,
            "name": "Marmot",
            "offset": 19,
            "length": 6
          }
        ],
        "0": [
          {
            "id": 1207059,
            "name": "Dhiren Patel",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 12
          }
        ]
      }, 
 . . .
}
```

Each tag within the story_tags field is **indexed by its offset** to where the object is referenced within the story field.

More info: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/592/

Comment: Hello eseceve, I tried with

`"message_tags" : {
 "0" : [{
 "id" : XXXXXXXXX,
 "name" : "Name and Surname",
 "offset" : 0,
 "length" : 16
 }]
}`

message is posted but user tag don't appear on facebook website

Comment: Hi @stefanodiluca That bug was reported on November 22. Subscribe to know when fixed. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/143145659124693?browse=search_4f3f474fdac1d8839692643)

Answer (score 0):

its a readonly object. Try :

```
   FB.api('/me/posts', { limit: 3 }, function(response) {
  for (var i=0, l=response.length; i<l; i++) {
    var post = response[i];
    if (post.message) {
      alert('Message: ' + post.message);
    } else if (post.attachment && post.attachment.name) {
      alert('Attachment: ' + post.attachment.name);
    }
  }
});
```

And set a breakpoint and read the response object, it contains the message_tags.

/J